# How to add new colum into Identity RoleClaims table (asp net core)

Tags: asp.net-core, identity, roles, claims

I'm trying to add a column to the identity (asp net core) RoleClaims table but I find content just to extend the roles and users classes and not to RoleClaims.
Could someone help with examples or point out content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to create a new class to extend the `RoleClaim`. Here is an example of how to do it if your key type is `string`:

```
public class ApplicationRoleClaim : IdentityRoleClaim<string>
{
    public virtual ApplicationRole Role { get; set; }
}
```

You can add whatever new properties you want to this class then create a migration to add them as table columns.

You would also need to tell your `IdentityDbContext` to use this new class as well. Here is an example from the docs:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext
    : IdentityDbContext<
        ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, string,
        ApplicationUserClaim, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserLogin,
        ApplicationRoleClaim, ApplicationUserToken>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

With your custom `ApplicationRoleClaim` class, you could override `OnModelCreating` as well. This is an example from the docs:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    ⋮
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRoleClaim<string>>(b =>
    {
        b.ToTable("MyRoleClaims");
    });
    ⋮
}
```

Reference: [Identity model customization in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model#add-all-navigation-properties)

Comment: I did as suggested, but the migration does not apply the changes

Comment: @Rafael Uemura Make sure you reference the docs, specifically around overriding the `OnModelCreating` method in the context. I will edit the answer to give some more detail.

Comment: @Rafael Uemura Also I don't think you want primitives to be `virtual` (i.e. you mention `virtual bool Active`) - that is only for navigation properties.

Answer (score 0):

I made a demo with asp.net core 2.2 and it worked well ,try the following code , customize `ApplicationRoleClaim` to add other propertyies.

```
public class ApplicationRoleClaim: IdentityRoleClaim<string>
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Then use `DbSet<TEntity>` class which represents a collection for a given entity within the model and is the gateway to database operations against an entity to add the new column to table

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {

    }

    public DbSet<ApplicationRoleClaim> ApplicationRoleClaim { get; set; }
}
```

Finally add-migration and update-database.