# Is it possible to add new columns in Identity RoleClaims table in ASP.NET Core and get all column's value

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I add some extra columns into the ASP.NET Core identity RoleClaims table:

[image]

Customize the class:

```
public class tbl_SYS_AspNet_RoleClaims : IdentityRoleClaim<Int32>
{  
        public int? CompanyID { get; set; }
        public int? ModuleID { get; set; }
        public int? FK_MenuID { get; set; }
        public bool? IsShowMenuInGroup { get; set; }
        public bool? Permission_New { get; set; }
        public bool? Permission_Edit { get; set; }
        public bool? Permission_Del { get; set; }
        public bool? Permission_View { get; set; }
        public bool? Permission_Print { get; set; }
        public bool? Permission_Export { get; set; }
        public bool? Permission_Import { get; set; }
        public bool? Permission_Report { get; set; }
        public bool? Permission_Others { get; set; }

        public virtual tbl_SYS_AspNet_Roles Role { get; set; }
}
```

In modelBuilder adding properties

```
modelBuilder.Entity<tbl_SYS_AspNet_RoleClaims>(b =>
            {
                b.ToTable("tbl_SYS_AspNet_RoleClaims");
                b.Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnType("int");
                b.Property(p => p.RoleId).HasColumnName("FK_RoleID").HasColumnType("int");
                b.Property(p => p.CompanyID).IsRequired(false);
                b.Property(p => p.ModuleID).IsRequired(false);
                b.Property(p => p.FK_MenuID).IsRequired(false);
                b.Property(p => p.IsShowMenuInGroup).IsRequired(false);
                b.Property(p => p.Permission_New).IsRequired(false);
                b.Property(p => p.Permission_Edit).IsRequired(false);
                b.Property(p => p.Permission_Del).IsRequired(false);
                b.Property(p => p.Permission_View).IsRequired(false);
                b.Property(p => p.Permission_Print).IsRequired(false);
                b.Property(p => p.Permission_Export).IsRequired(false);
                b.Property(p => p.Permission_Import).IsRequired(false);
                b.Property(p => p.Permission_Report).IsRequired(false);
                b.Property(p => p.Permission_Others).IsRequired(false);
            });
```

and to fetch all values I write this code:

```
 var roleclaims = await this.roleManager.GetClaimsAsync(role);
```

My expectation is that the code will fetch all columns and rows as shown the screenshot:

[image]

but it's not:

[image]

My question: am I doing this in the correct way? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add new colum into Identity RoleClaims table (asp net core)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57792378/how-to-add-new-colum-into-identity-roleclaims-table-asp-net-core)

Comment: @viveknuna not addressing my problem